# Can I reference text throughout word as I would in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology as I know referencing is something different but I am creating a **Word** document with standards at the top eg. `speed = 30`. Can I have this `30` appear throughout the document with the source of the information coming from the standards at the top?

Similarly, in excel I can just have `=C5` everywhere, and then if I want to change this information throughout the spreadsheet I can just change `C5` once and all other values will update?

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, this can be done.***

### The simplest way is with Mapped Content Controls.

There are a number of these built into Word in the misnamed "Document Property" Content Controls under Quick Parts. Here is [my page on repurposing these](https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart). Here is a [video on doing this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAskwzL7zbI).

Here is a [video on creating your own custom mapped content controls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtFhIqK0gec).

Here is [Greg Maxey's page on all the ways you can automatically repeat data in Word](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/repeating_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making use of Quick Parts in the Insert tab in MS Word.

However, first enable the **Developer** tab in MS Word. It's pretty simple, but different for some older versions, and the detailed instructions can be found here:
[How to add Developer tab in MS Word](https://wordaddins.com/support/how-to-add-developer-tab-in-word/).

This is the sample text that I have taken in MS Word:
[image: Sample text]

Now, we will put in the value for Speed in such a way that it appears throughout the document with the source of the information coming from the top of the document.

Go to `Insert>>Quick Parts>>Document Property>>Abstract` (Don't worry, we'll change the placeholder called `Abstract` to `Speed`)

Select the Placeholder (*i.e.,* `Abstract` here), go to **Developer** tab, Click **Properties** and change the **Title** to **Speed** and add Tag as **Speed**. Then Click OK.

Now put inside the box that says `Speed` the desired value:

[image: Speed value]

Select `Speed` and **Copy** as follows:

[image: copied]

Now put the cursor where you want this value to appear in the next parts of the document. Under the **Home** tab, open **Clipboard** and click the value of Speed which will appear there:

[image: Speed]

You'll see that the value of the speed will be filled in there automatically:

[image: auto change]

Now, whenever you change the value of speed in the topmost (Standards) part of the document, other values in the documents will change automatically:

[image: Finally]

Similarly, you can use this method for other values also. I hope this helps :)